# Show that the number of simple graphs with $n$ vertices is $2^{{n}\choose{2}}$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, proof-explanation

There is something about the proof showing that the number of simple graphs with $n$ vertices is $2^{{n}\choose{2}}$ I don't quite understand.

We know that $2^n$ is the number of subsets of sets with $n$ items. So why shouldn't the number of simple graphs generated from $n$ vertices be $2^n$ instead of $2^{{n}\choose{2}}$.

*For example, if I have a three vertices, the number of simple graphs generated is exactly $2^3 = 8$.*

What does ${{n}\choose{2}}$ mean exactly in this scenario? Why not ${{n}\choose{3}}$?

Comment: $\binom{n}{r}=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$ is the binomial coefficient "$n$ choose $r$", the number of ways of selecting $r$ objects from $n$ distinguishable objects.  You should know $\binom{n}{2}$ is the number of possible edges in an $n$ element graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a simple labeled graph with $n$ vertices there are $\binom{n}{2}$ pairs of vertices.  Edges directly correspond to pairs of vertices.  There are $\binom{n}{2}$ possible locations for edges to be then.

Applying multiplication principle to the string of questions "Is this edge in the graph: yes or no (*2 options*)" we get then a total possible number of collections of edges as $2^{\binom{n}{2}}$.  As each graph on $n$ vertices is uniquely described by which edges are present in the graph, we get the result.

Comment: Hi, I know that ${n}\choose{k}$ represents the number of ways of ordering $k$ indistinguishable objects in a set of $n$ objects. Then  ${n}\choose{2}$ represents the number of ways of ordering $2$ indistinguishable objects in a set of $n$ objects. I am not sure how this definition translate into the number of possible locations for edges. I guess I will need to look up the proof for this

Comment: @DetectiveMooch [see this related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17747/why-a-complete-graph-has-fracnn-12-edges?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Thanks. I am a very visual person and I have a very difficult time in seeing why certain combinatorics argument is true. In the first answer, I can clearly visualize edges coming out of a vertex and the idea becomes very intuitive.