# Number of Connected simple graphs with n vertices

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

Is there a relation between numbers of simple graphs and simple connected graphs on n vertices? After observing n=1,2,3,4...., I noticed that the number of connected graphs is at least half of the total number of simple graphs. How can we prove that?

Answer (score 1):

The number of nonisomorphic simple graphs is [A88](https://oeis.org/A000088) and the number of connected simple graphs is [A1349](https://oeis.org/A001349) in the OEIS. They are related by the Euler transform; this is a special case of the [Multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) Transformation, which means the not necessarily connected graphs are multisets of the connected graphs.

Answer (score 0):

For the part where you asked for Number of Simple Graphs with N vertices I will refer you to a proof in this link as it has been answered here.

[Show that the number of simple graphs with $n$ vertices is $2^{{n}\choose{2}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2451114/show-that-the-number-of-simple-graphs-with-n-vertices-is-2n-choose2)

Comment: How is a connected graph a tree? Every $K_n$ is connected but rarely a tree

Comment: Oh I will edit By defination I assumed that there are no cycles  in this graph

Comment: But if n = 4, the formula gives 2^6 = 64, but we know that the number of simple graphs with 4 vertices is 11.

Comment: @RachelWu How do you count?

Comment: @RachelWu I think for N=4 the number of non isomorphic Simple Graphs is 11 , I have just stated for Simple Graphs which is 2^6. which is correct by defination

Comment: oh, so 64 includes the isomorphic graphs?